# Handling a time-stamp in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, timestamp

In firebase realtime database, something seemingly basic does not work.

Here is the JS code:

```
  let myDBRef = firebase.database().ref('MyCollection');
  newItem = myDBRef.push(),
  startTime = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
  endTime = startTime + 24*3600*1000
  newItem.set({
    someField:'myFieldValue',
    startTime:startTime,
    endTime:endTime
  });
```

I expect something like the following in the DB as a result:

```
  -MXb9s2-3mX3XZL_azRv
      endTime: 1601691254295
      someField: "myFieldValue"
      startTime: 1601604854295
```

But I get this instead:

```
  -MXb9s2-3mX3XZL_azRv
      endTime: "[object Object]86400000"
      someField: "myFieldValue"
      startTime: 1601604854295
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I need to change the JS code to get the result I expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` is not the current server-side timestamp, but a marker value that gets translated to the actual server-side timestamp when written to the database.

That means that you can't store calculated values like you do now in a single step. You have two options:

1. Store the `duration` instead of the `endTime`. So:

   ```
   let myDBRef = firebase.database().ref('MyCollection');
   newItem = myDBRef.push(),
   startTime = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
   duration = 24*3600*1000
   newItem.set({
     someField:'myFieldValue',
     startTime:startTime,
     duration:duration
   });
   ```
2. Store the `startTime` first, and then calculate the `endTime` either in the client or in a Cloud Function, that then updates the database. This'd be something like:

   ```
   let myDBRef = firebase.database().ref('MyCollection');
   newItem = myDBRef.push(),
   startTime = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
   duration = 24*3600*1000
   newItem.set({
     someField:'myFieldValue',
     startTime:startTime,
   }).then(() => {
     newItem.child("startTime").once("value").then((snapshot) => {
       newItem.update({ endTime: snapshot.val() + duration });
     })
   })
   ```

Comment: OK. That makes sense, I will try that. But I suppose you meant: "duration = 24*3600*1000" and not "duration + 24*3600*1000". Right?

Comment: I edited the post to fix it and accepted the answer.